# AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have an html code

```
a = <th scope="row">Optical properties</th>
```

and want output = "Optical properties"
I tried following  code but it gave error

```
a.get_text()
a.string
a.text
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

According the title of your question, the variable `a` holds `ResultSet`. To access the text of the first item in this result set, you can do:

```
a[0].get_text()
```

---

Or:

```
soup.find('th').text
```